# Enter and stepwise regression

Tags: regression, methodology

I found a significantly predictive model using the enter method of regression. Is it ok to then go on to perform a stepwise method of regression (within the same report, and report the results of both) to further narrow down the predictors? Or is this something that should be left for a future report? I wasnt sure if it would be justifiable within the same study. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't do stepwise. Not now, not later, not as part of this report and not as part of a later report.  All the output is wrong when you do stepwise.

Comment: @PeterFlom, I tend to agree that stepwise is unwise. I have found it useful on some occasions and cannot reject it for all situations.

Comment: Well, as long as you realize that all of the output is demonstably wrong and never publish results from a stepwise regression, it might have some use somewhere. I guess you could use it on a training data set. But the parameter estimates, p values and standard errors are all wrong.

Comment: The objection against stepwise is mostly that p values and such criteria are wrong? If I would do some other form of regression with parameter selection/tuning then this does not occur?